# Roku - How to play music in background of Slideshow?

Tags: slideshow, roku, brightscript

I am new to Roku & Brightscript programming. I want to play music in the background while showing photos from my album in the thumb drive.

I found this [awesome project on Github](https://github.com/decadeofdefeat/roku-animated-slideshow) which plays Slideshows. Trying to figure out a way to play music in background. I tried to plug in the audio player into the code.. audio doesn't play.

Here is code addition to the above [Github project](https://github.com/decadeofdefeat/roku-animated-slideshow) 
**Newslideshow method I added:**

```
   ns.Initialize = init
   ns.Show       = show_screen
   ns.EventLoop  = event_loop

   ns.PlayMusic = play_music  '<-- wired music player

   ns.Draw    = slideshow_draw
   ns.DrawAll = slideshow_drawall
```

**Player Code:**

```
Function show_screen() As Void
   m.Screen = CreateObject("roScreen", True)
   m.Screen.SetMessagePort(m.Port)
  'm.Screen.SetAlphaEnable(True)
   m.Compositor.SetDrawTo(m.Screen, m.ScrBkgClr)

   m.DrawAll()

   m.PlayMusic() '<--Added handler

   m.EventLoop()

End Function

Function play_music() as Void
    print "music"

    m.AudioPlayer = CreateObject("roAudioPlayer")    
    m.AudioPlayer.SetMessagePort(m.Port)    

    song = CreateObject("roAssociativeArray")
    song.url = "http://lobbytv.azurewebsites.net/api/music/01.mp3/"
    m.Audioplayer.addcontent(song)
    m.Audioplayer.setloop(false)
    m.AudioPlayer.play()

    'm.EventLoop()
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it cannot resolve stream format. Try setting it:

```
song.streamFormat = "mp3"
```

Comment: this works.. couldn't have guessed this.. as it worked without this when running just music. Thanks a Lot....